# Duplicate StickyHeader in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I am relatively new to AngularJs and I am trying to duplicate a Stick Header Jquery Plugin I have seen used on the internet, but for some reason when I attempt to do it in an "Angular" version it does not work:

```
($window).scroll(function() {
                            var sticky = $('.sticky'),
                                scroll = ($window).scrollTop();

                            if (scroll >= 100) sticky.addClass('fixed');
                            else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
```

Comment: To do this you should create a directive.  When I get to a computer, I'll give the html and JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Here is how I would do it.

Html:

```
<div class="sticky">
    The directive will bind to this snippet by the class.  
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
       .directive("sticky", ["$window", function($window){
           return ({
               link: link,
               restrict: "C"
           });
           function link(scope, element, attrs){
               angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                   if($window.pageYOffset >= 100){
                      angular.element(element).addClass("fixed");
                   }else{
                      angular.element(element).removeClass("fixed");
                   }
               });
           }
       }]);
```